# How to install git on RHEL6.7

Tags: redhat, git

I'm trying to install Git on a RHEL6.7 distributor ID:Santiago development server, But after using yum install git, it is showing error

> Error Downloading Packages:
>     1:perl-Error-0.17015-4.el6.noarch: failure: Packages/perl-Error-0.17015-4.el6.                                                                                                                     noarch.rpm from SERVER: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
>     git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64: failure: Packages/git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.x86_64.rpm f                                                                                                                     rom SERVER: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
>     perl-Git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.noarch: failure: Packages/perl-Git-1.7.1-3.el6_4.1.no

Comment: If you don't have a RHEL subscription, you can't install packages. CentOS would be a free alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You have problems with network connectivity to repository mirrors. Try to execute `yum clean all` and install git again.

Comment: After using 

yum clean all

Now it is showing:

Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Cleaning repos: SERVER
Cleaning up Everything

Comment: Then register your system with RedHat.